# How can I get the reddit hat?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've taken part in the 2013 April fool's reddit event and now it's finally payday for this old tired mercenary.

How can I disgrace my forehead by donning that ridiculous homewreck of a headgear?

Comment: Emphasis on the 'disgrace.'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Log in with your eligible reddit account.
2. Visit http://reddit.com/f2p/steam and log in with Steam.
3. Stare blankly at your newly acquired genuine string of metal.

You'll get the slightly better [Conspiracy Cap](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Conspiracy_Cap) if you were on team Orangered during the event. This soldier wasn't on Orangered, so he has to make do with the [Public Accessor](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Public_Accessor).

> [image]

He isn't having a great time.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know I was eligible until I stumbled across this question!

Comment: I went to this link it was a 404

Comment: @DavidYell It might be that the window to get the hat has closed, then :(